# Difference IDS/IPS layer 2 or 3

Tags: ids

I understand that an IDS/IPS working on layer 2 has more insight into what is going on. 
But considering IDS/IPS evasions, why is a layer 2 device preferable as compared to a layer 3 device that is still investigating on the same layer where the attacks are occuring ?

Thanks in advance,
ken

Comment: What do you mean, "L2 has more insight"? Who said that L2 is more preferable than L3? There's a ton of assumptions here that needs to be sorted out.

Comment: I'm not familiar with any IDS/IPS specific meaning to 'layer 2' or 'layer 3'.  I suppose you could point to IDS/IPS that can't consider layer 2 information when triggering events or haven't done a good job of recognizing layer 2 evasions, but I've never heard that problem described that way.